# How does "public private(set)" access modifiers work?

Tags: swift, struct, access-modifiers

So I'm going through the Apple docs here - [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)

Then I ran into this:

```swift
public struct TrackedString {
    public private(set) var numberOfEdits = 0
    public var value: String = "" {
        didSet {
            numberOfEdits += 1
        }
    }
    public init() {}
}
```

How does adding `public private(set)` exactly work? If you can show some easier examples/explanation that would be amazing!

Answer (score 80):

This just means that the getter for `numberOfEdits` is public, but the setter is private. There's nothing more to it.

The reason in this case is so that you can read `numberOfEdits` publicly, but you can only set it via changing `value`. If it were fully `public`, then anyone could set it, but if it were only settable, then the `didSet` in `value` couldn't modify it. `private(set)` is a compromise between those two.

Comment: The explanation is correct, but the variable mentioned is wrong.  The numberOfEdits property is the one that can be set only from within the class (i.e. read-only everywhere else).  The value property is still read/write everywhere.

Comment: @conarch "The numberOfEdits property is the one that can be set only from within the class" Not the class. The file. Class scoping of privacy has not yet been implemented in Swift.

Answer (score 27):

This property can be **read**, but cannot be set from the **outside**.

You assign a lower access level by writing `private(set)`.

Its works like ***Public getter*** and ***Private setter***.

```
//MARK:- Foo
class Foo {
    private var name: String
    private var ID: String

   //initialize
   init(name:String, ID:String){
      self.name = name
      self.ID = ID
   }
}
```

We will get an error when to try to access `private` variable.

[image: privateAccessLevel]

But we can fix this error in a single line by changing `private` access level to `private(set)`.

```
//MARK:- Foo
class Foo {
    private(set) var name: String
    private var ID: String

   //initialize
   init(name:String, ID:String) {
       self.name = name
       self.ID = ID
   }
}
```

So you can easy access the private variable, constant, property, or subscript.

```
//Access class value from Foo
let fooObjc = Foo.init(name: "test", ID: "9900")
print(fooObjc.name)
```

Use `fileprivate(set)`, `private(set)`, and `internal(set)` to change the access level of this synthesized setter in exactly the same way as for an explicit setter in a computed property.

***This property can be read, but cannot be set from the outside.***

Ref: [Click the link to know more](https://iostree.wordpress.com/2020/04/18/privateset-getters-and-setters/)

Comment: In your last example `private(set) var` is actually `let`. – `private(set) var` is only useful if the value is going to be modified inside the class (the `init` method doesn't count).

Comment: It worked for me, thanks a lot for the help.
Moreover, if you want this var to be readable (Objective-C and Swift) publically and settable privately then you can do the following:
@objc public private(set) var myVar: String = ""

Answer (score 5):

`private (set) var` limits write access to internal scope, but still allows external read access. The var can also be read internally.

For example, compare `private var` to `private (set) var`:

`private`

```
class NameNotAccessible {
    private var name: String?
}

var person = NameNotAccessible()
print(person.name) // ERROR: external access forbidden
```

Modified to `private (set) var`

```
class NameAccessible {
    private (set) var name: String? // externally readable, internally writable
}

var person2 = NameAccessible()
print(person2.name) // external read OK
person2.name = "Jacob" // ERROR: external write forbidden
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @Sivabalaa Jothibose and @craft
It worked for me, thanks a lot for the help.

Moreover, if you want this var to be readable (Objective-C and Swift) publically and settable privately then you can do the following:

```
@objc public private(set) var myVar: String = ""
```